# Converting a list of strings to a single pattern

Tags: python, redis

I have a list of strings that follow a specific pattern.  Here's an example

```
['ratelimiter:foobar:201401011157',
 'ratelimiter:foobar:201401011158',
 'ratelimiter:foobar:201401011159',
 'ratelimiter:foobar:201401011200']
```

I'm trying to end up with a blob pattern that will represent this list like the following

```
'ratelimiter:foobar:201401011*
```

I know the first two fields ahead of time.  The third field is a time stamp and I want to find the column at which they start to have different values from other values in the column.

In the example given the timestamp ranges from 2014-01-01-11:57 to 2014-01-01-12:00 and the column that's different is the third to the last column where 1 changes to 2. If I can find that, then I can slice the string to `[:-3] += '*'` (for this example)

Every time I try and tackle this problem I end up with loops everywhere.  I just feel like there's a better way of doing this.

Or maybe someone knows a better way of doing this with `redis`. I'm doing this because I'm trying to get keys from `redis` and I don't want to make a request for every key but rather make a batch request using the pattern parameter.  Maybe there's a better way of doing this but haven't found anything yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staying in the pattern thing (converting to timestamp is probably best, though), I would do that to find the longest prefix:

```
items = ['ratelimiter:foobar:201401011157',
 'ratelimiter:foobar:201401011158',
 'ratelimiter:foobar:201401011159',
 'ratelimiter:foobar:201401011200']

print items[0][:[len(set(x)) == 1 for x in zip(*items)].index(False)] + '*'
# ratelimiter:foobar:201401011*
```

Which reads as: cut the first element of `items` where all nth elements of `items` are no longer equals.

`[len(set(x)) == 1 for x in zip(*items)]` will return a list of boolean being True for i if all elements at i are equal across `items`

Answer (score 2):

This is what I will do:

1. convert the timestamp to numbers
2. find the max and min (if your list is not ordered)
3. take the difference between max and min and convert it back to pattern.

For example, in your case, the difference between max and min is 43. And the min is already 57, you can quickly deduct that if the min ends with ***157, the max should be ***200. And you know the pattern

Answer (score 1):

You almost never want to use the '*' parameter in Redis in production because it is very slow-- much slower than making a request for each key individually in the vast majority of cases. Unless you're requesting so many keys that your bottleneck becomes the sheer amount of data you're transferring over the network (in which case you should really convert things to [Lua](http://www.redisgreen.net/blog/intro-to-lua-for-redis-programmers/) and run the logic server-side), a [pipeline](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining) is really want you want.

The reason you want a pipeline is you're probably getting hit by the costs of transferring data back and forth between your Redis server in separate hops right now. A pipeline, in contrast, queues up a bunch of commands to run against Redis, and then executes them all at once, when you're ready. Assuming you're using [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py) (if you're not, you really should be), and `r` is your connection to your Redis server, you can do this like so:

```
r = redis.Redis(...)
pipe = r.pipeline()
items = ['ratelimiter:foobar:201401011157',
 'ratelimiter:foobar:201401011158',
 'ratelimiter:foobar:201401011159',
 'ratelimiter:foobar:201401011200']
for item in items:
    pipe.get(item)
#all the values for each item you're getting from Redis will be here.
item_values = pipe.execute()
```

**Note**: this will only make one call to Redis and will be much faster than either getting each value individually or running a pattern selection.

All of the other answers so far are good Python answers, but you're dealing with a Redis problem. You need a Redis answer.